# I can't log in to user

Tags: wordpress

I add users through the profile builder plugin and then I get the user for me, and when I add a user through the wp insert and try to log in, I write that the password is not correct. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to expand on your question. Where have you installed WordPress? What versions of Wordpress, PHP, webserver. Link to the plugin you need help with. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wp_create_user() function to create user in wordpress. Check the function :  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

Comment: Who cares?
Still saved with wp insert. Just log the problem

Comment: it's main function to create wordpress user. But you can also do using wp_insert().  In your case it seems you are not encrypting the password  wp_hash_password(Your Password) before inserting. 

For more info -  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2110
check wp_insert_user() function